# Change MainViewController in ios with Swift after login

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Hello Friends My name is Tony dhand. I am new in IOS development. Now i am trying to fix a problem . I am going to login in ios app and after login display the dashboard.

But when i restart the app it again show the login screen. For this i want to change the initialview at the start of the app after login in other words i want to change the view at the startup .I don't know what to do. please help me for resolving this problem or give your idea for this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Just change rootviewcontroller after login.

Comment: Just review this Question :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28366407/switching-view-controller-after-login-best-practise

Answer (score 3):

When the user logs in successfully you can save the "Login Status" as -

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
defaults.synchronize()
```

Then in the "AppDelegate.swift" file you can check the login status when the app launches in the "didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" function as -

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let isUserLoggedIn = defaults.boolForKey("isUserLoggedIn")

    if(!isUserLoggedIn) {
        self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController")
    } else {
        self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    }

    return true
}
```

Finally when the user logs out you can change the logged in status as false as -

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "isUserLoggedIn")
defaults.synchronize()

let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController")
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nice answer and also a profile picture..upvoted and liked :D

Answer (score 1):

Keep the status of the login in your NSUserDefaults. When you login successfully, then set it as TRUE for the Key.

So Next time when you launch the app, check the value of the variable stored in NSUserDefaults in AppDelegate.

If its true then your Login SUCCESS, then navigate to your dashboardViewController. Otherwise navigate to your login Page ViewController.

Enter the following code after successful login

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:TRUE forKey:@"isLogin"];
```

Add the following code in your AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingOptions.

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"isLogin"]) {
   // Already Logged in         
  //  Set your Dashboard Page as Root View Controller
}
else{
   // Not Logged in
  //  Set your Login Page as Root View Controller
}
```

Hope it helps...